# How do I get SV_Target1 texture in Universal-RP

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering

I'm trying to write value in SV_Target1 in object's material and get it in post-processing feature in urp. But I dont know how I can get Texture rendered in SV_Target1. It's not exist guide even in Shader semantics Unity menual! Is it any good references or tutorial about it?

Install Urp and make shader feature and shader and add it,